# Ubuntu 14.04 Gigabyte p25w, no sound

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, realtek

I'm currently trying to play music on my laptop, but I can't get any sound from it.

I have a gigabyte p25w with Ubuntu 14.04 and two audio devices, default HDA Intel and realtek ACL282.

I did some research on google, and it seems that the wrong output device is set.

I edited the `alsa-base.conf` file to change the default device (`options <driver> index=0`) but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally succeeded in changing the default audio device to the ACL282 through Mutimedia audio selector, then i had to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to unmute the computer...